# How can I troubleshoot a Rancher HA deployment cert-manager issue on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, rancher

I am new to both Rancher and K8s.

I walked through the Rancher HA documentation and deployed a 3-node cluster on AWS with a Layer 4 Load Balanced configured.

Everything indicates that the deployment was successful, but I am having issues with certificates. When I go to the sit after install (https://rancher.domain.net), I am prompted with an un-trusted site warning. I accept the risk , then the page just hangs. I can see the rancher favicon, but the page never loads.

I opted for the self-signed certs to get it up and running. My AWS NLB is just forward 443 and 80 to the target groups and not using a ACM provided cert.

I checked these two settings per the documentation:

```
$ kubectl -n cattle-system describe certificate
No resources found in castle-system namespace.
```

```
$ kubectl -n cattle-system describe issuer
No resources found in castle-system namespace.
```

Describe issuer originally showed what looked like appropriate output, but that is no longer showing anything.

I rand this command:

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager
NAME                                          READY         STATUS       RESTARTS          AGE
cert-manager-**********-*****                 1/1           Running      0                 34m
cert-manager-caininjector-**********-*****    1/1           Running      0                 34m
cert-manager-webhook-**********-*****         1/1           Running      0                 34m
```

At this point, I am beyond my experience and would appreciate some pointers on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: There are some inaccuracies in your question. You invoke your command with `-n cattle-system` and you get output with `castle-system`. Is this expected, is this a typo? Please run `kubectl get cert --all-namespaces`. `Issuer` is a namespaced resource, and it is not possible to issue certificates from an `Issuer` in a different namespace. This means you will need to create an `Issuer` in each namespace you wish to obtain Certificates in. You can check the `ClusterIssuer` resource in that situation. Additionally please tell which `Ingress` controller you are intending to use.

Answer (score 0):

List the services. What is the status of the rancher service?

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get services
```

Can you describe the rancher service object?

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe service <rancher service>
```

or

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get service <rancher service> -o json
```

Is it of type Loadbalancer, i.e. did you let Kubernetes AWS Cloud provider create the NLB or did you create it outside of K8S? If you can better to let Kubernetes create the LB.

Reference for tweaking the [cloud providers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) via annotations.